# Different behaviour shown when running the same code for a file and for a list

Tags: python-3.x, list, file

I have observed this unusual behaviour when I try to do a string slicing on the words in a file and the words in a list.Both the results are quite different.

For example I have a file 'words.txt' which contains the following content

```
POPE
POPS
ROPE
POKE
COPE
PAPE
NOPE
POLE
```

When I write the below piece of code, I expect to get a list of words with last letter omitted.

```
with open("words.txt", "r") as fo:
    for l in fo:
        print(l[:-1])
```

But instead I get this result below.No string slicing takes place and the words are similar as before.

```
POPE
POPS
ROPE
POKE
COPE
PAPE
NOPE
POLE
```

But if I write the below code, I get what I want

```
lis = ["POPE", "POPS", "ROPE", "POKE", "COPE", "PAPE", "NOPE", "POLE"]
for i in lis:
    print(i[:-1])
```

I am able to delete the last letter of each of the words as expected.

```
POP
POP
ROP
POK
COP
PAP
NOP
POL
```

So why do I see two different results for the same operation [: -1] ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line ends with `\n` in files where as you dont need line endings in lists.

Your actual file contents are as follows

```
POPE\n
POPS\n
ROPE\n
POKE\n
COPE\n
PAPE\n
NOPE\n
POLE\n
```

hence the `print(l[:-1])` is actually trimming the line ending i.e. `\n`.

To verify this, declare an empty list before the loop, and add each line to that list and print it. You will find the that the lines contain the `\n` on every line

```
stuff = []

with open("words.txt", "r") as fo:
     for line in fo:
         stuff.append(line)

print stuff
```

this will print `['POPE\n', 'POPS\n', 'ROPE\n', 'POKE\n']`

---

If I am not wrong, you want to carry out the slicing operation on the file contents. I think you should look into [`strip()` method](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html).

Comment: Hey thanks a lot! Your answer is really informative!

Comment: Welcome! Do use google more, google is your friend, so are print statements

Comment: I did but they only talked about methods like splitlines(), strip() etc.Didn't know this was going on behind the scenes.